# Initialize a carousel of varying size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Bit of a newb to the web development game. I'm building a portfolio site centered around ice hockey and I'm using some API data I got from a free public NHL API. I was hoping to use a carousel/slider to show a schedule of today's NHL games, with one slide per game. The problem, as you might imagine is that there are a different number of games each day, so I can't do a slider that has a set number of slides. Is there a way to initialize a carousel based on the number of games there are that day and then use the API data to fill in the specifics on each slide using Javascript or JQuery? I've searched online for this problem and can't seem to find anything that has been helpful to me.

Comment: [Carousels are not used by most users](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective). They should almost never be used.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).